# voiceStateUpdate event doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, discord, discord.js

I have a problem since the v13 update of discord.js. I can log the channels (oldState, newState) but the code is not executing and returns no errors!

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', async (oldState, newState) => {

    console.log(oldState) //I got the channel on the console
 
    //But the lines below not work at all since the v13 update
    if(oldState.channelID == '825407723129536543') {
        console.log(`old state is > ${oldState.channelID}`)

        if(oldState.channel.members.size == 0) {
            oldChannel = client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "test")
            client.channels.cache.find(c => c.name == "test").clone(undefined, true, false, 'Needed a clone')
            .then(oldChannel.delete())
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: your code seems fine, have you enabled the [intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) for your bot and passed them in your code?

Comment: I found the problem by myself, it was "channelId" and not "channelID".